# Are there differences in memory allocation between Java 8 vs. Java 9?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wanted to experiment with the -Xmx option in Java and created a simple test program that allocates 1 Mib at the time until it runs out of memory.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class MemoryMuncher {
    static final int MiB = 1048576;
    static final int accellerator = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector victor = new Vector();
        int i = 1;
        try {
            while (true) {
                byte roger[] = new byte[MiB * accellerator];
                victor.add(roger);
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                System.out.printf("free: %,6d\t\ttotal: %,6d\t\tallocated: %,6d \n", rt.freeMemory()/MiB, rt.totalMemory()/MiB, i++*accellerator);
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program with the -Xmx option, I'm noticing a difference in behavior between Java 8 (1.8.0.131) and Java 9 (9.0.1).

**Java 8** works close to what I would expect. When I run the program with -Xmx256M,  it allocates 233MiB before throwing an OutOfMemoryError.

```
free:    361        total:    368       allocated:      1 
free:    360        total:    368       allocated:      2 
...
free:     12        total:    245       allocated:    232 
free:     11        total:    245       allocated:    233 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

However, when I run the same program with **Java 9**, it only gets about *halfway* (127 MiB) before I get the exception. This is consistent. If I change the -Xmx to 512M  or 1024M, it only gets to half of that amount (255 MiB and 510 MiB respectively). I have no explanation for this behavior.

```
free:    250        total:    256       allocated:      1 
free:    247        total:    256       allocated:      2 
...
free:      2        total:    256       allocated:    126 
free:      1        total:    256       allocated:    127 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have searched the documentation for any changes in memory management between Java 8 and Java 9, but did not find anything.

Does anyone have any insight why Java 9 would manage/allocate memory differently in some cases from previous Java versions?

Comment: Why do you care about Java 9? It's [eol](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html). Java 11 is out.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior on Java 10 and/or one of the Java 11 early releases?

Comment: I do see the same thing with Java 10. I used Java 9 in the example because that's where the change started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-9/) very interesting article about how Java 9 planned to garbage collect differently.

More specifically, Java 9 plans to use the G1 Garbage collector which divides memories into fixed sizes. What your code may be doing is triggering the memory to split into two fixed size blocks for Java 9. The reason it would do this is that it would save the other half of memory for moving everything and 'compacting' the memory still in use. However, because you just keep using memory, it would just break immediately when ~1/2 the memory was used. I'm not sure how rigorous of an CS you may have, but at my school we studied simple garbage techniques, and one such simple one that G1GC reminds me of is the [stop-and-copy](http://wiki.c2.com/?StopAndCopy) technique which switches the allocated memory between halves of memory while it 'compacts' the memory as it does this.

With Java 8, the Parallel Collector is used, which does is different from the G1GC as all it cares about is throughput. Thus, closer to 100% of the true heap will be used, at the cost of longer GC times. Of course, this is a tradeoff between the two versions, but you can get around this be explicitly specifying the kind of GC to use. For example, if on Java 9 you use the option:

```
-XX:UseParallelGC
```

you should see the same behavior as you do with Java 8. The article I linked has all the different options, but I think you get the idea. Hope this helps/answer your question, I actually didn't realize this until you brought it up, so thank you for making me aware of this.

**EDIT:** According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html) themselves, they say that the new G1 garbage collector is intended for high memory machines, again giving reason why they would not utilize the full heap space to spend less time GC-ing.

Comment: That appears to be it. Very nice explanation.

Comment: Although to challenge your answer a little: in Java 9, if I allocate 1 MB at a time, I run out of memory when about half the memory is used. So if I have 256 MiB, it stops at 126 MiB. **However**, when I allocate 2MB at a time, I run out of memory at 168 Mib. If I allocate 3, it stops at 189 Mib. I think you have the root cause, this must be due to the particulars of gc.

Comment: Yes, I would imagine the behavior is more complex than I described. I think the only way to really fully understand how g1gc works would be by looking at the code itself.